# Is there a script to merge two perforce depots?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have an old personal perforce server depot I had on my own machine.  Now I have a full version of perforce in work and I would like to move some of my personal stuff into the new perforce server.

I know I can simply sync the old server and then add all the files newly into the new server, however I would like if possible to retain the history of my project changes.  I appreciate the changelist numbers will have to change, however it would be great if I could get a script that will copy all the files and change from one depot to another.

Anyone know of a perforce script to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They provide a utility for combining Perforce servers that they call Perfmerge++.  Details about where to get it and how to use it can be found [here](http://kb.perforce.com/article/911).

Answer (score 0):

Perforce support have tools to assist you with this task.